# Detect monitor when system messages and notifications are displayed and dismissed?

Tags: ios, notifications, privacy

Sometimes an iOS system message will be displayed and interrupt an app. For example, a privacy system message might ask for access to a photo album or to use the microphone, or a system message might display a notification such as low battery.

What techniques can be used for iOS7/8/9 in Swift that detect and monitor when a system message or notification is displayed and also when it is dismissed?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to listen out for different alerts, one example being a privacy alert and once that privacy alert is accepted or declined by the user, do something related to that action.

Comment: Your own app will initiate a privacy alert therefore your own code can handle the result. There's no need to listen for system messages or notifications.

Comment: But my app possibly won't for system messages displayed such as a notification for low battery.

Comment: You have no control over those messages. There is no API to know when any of those are shown. Though your app may become inactive if it is the foreground app when the message appears and will be come active again when the message disappears. But that can happen for other reasons too.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to specifically achieve here, pinpointing those reasons the app becomes inactive and active. The answer below appears promising at pinpointing the reasons using springboard and Darwin notifications, however it isn't available in Swift, so I'm unable to determine if it works.

Answer (score 2):

So it looks like this can actually be accomplished with springboard notifications/Darwin notifications.  I've only tested this on reminder alerts so far and it appears to work great.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //com.apple.springboard.showingAlertItem
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self registerforDeviceLockNotif];
}


//call back
static void displayStatusChanged(CFNotificationCenterRef center, void *observer, CFStringRef name, const void *object, CFDictionaryRef userInfo) {


    NSString *lockState = (__bridge NSString*)name;
    NSLog(@"Darwin notification NAME = %@",name);

    if ([lockState isEqualToString:@"com.apple.springboard.showingAlertItem"]) {
        NSLog(@"Notification was shown");
    } 
}


-(void)registerforDeviceLockNotif {

     //Alert notification
      CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(), 
                                NULL, // observer
                                displayStatusChanged, // callback
                                   CFSTR("com.apple.springboard.showingAlertItem"), // event name
                                NULL, // object
                                CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorDeliverImmediately);


}
```

Here is a list of all of the different springboard notifications that you can listen for. Its possible that it may take a combination of a few of them to achieve exactly what you want.
[Full List](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/SpringBoard.app/Notifications)

`Name   Firmware
com.apple.springboard.bootedcleanly 2.0 –
com.apple.springboard.fullycharged  2.0 –
com.apple.springboard.pluggedin 2.0 –
com.apple.springboard.lockinterrupted   2.0 –
com.apple.springboard.callinterruptedapp    2.0 –
com.apple.airportsettingsvisible    3.0 –
com.apple.springboard.lockstate 2.0 –
com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete  2.0 –
com.apple.springboard.showingAlertItem  2.0 –
com.apple.springboard.lowPowerAlertPresented    2.0 –
com.apple.airport.userNotification  2.0 –
com.apple.mobile.SubstantialTransition  2.0 –
SignificantTimeChangeNotification   2.0 –
com.apple.powerlog.exit 3.0 –
com.apple.springboard.deviceWillShutDown    2.1 –
SBSpringBoardDidLaunchNotification  2.1 –
displayID-activated 2.2 –
displayID-suspended 2.0 –
com.apple.springboard.DeviceLockStatusChanged   2.0 –
SBDidTurnOnDisplayNotification  2.1 –
SBDidTurnOffDisplayNotification 2.1 –
com.apple.springboard.activeCallStateChanged    3.0 –
com.apple.springboard.attemptactivation 2.0 –
SBFormattedPhoneNumber  2.0 –
PSAirplaneModeChangedNotification   2.2 –
com.apple.alarm.alarmchanged    2.0 –
com.apple.alarm.alarmfired  2.0 –
com.apple.SpringBoard.ReadyForRestore   2.0 –
com.apple.springboard.syncingUnblocked  2.0 –
kGSCapabilityChangedNotification    2.0 –
com.apple.springboard.RentalsExpiredNotification    2.0 –
com.apple.remotenotification.notificationdelivered  3.0 –
SBRingerSilent  2.0 –
SBRinger1   2.0 –
com.apple.springboard.ringerstate   2.0 –
com.apple.springboard.doubleheightmode  3.0 –
com.apple.springboard.hasBlankedScreen  2.0 –
com.apple.springboard.unambiguousOrientation    2.0 –
com.apple.springboard.orientation   2.0 –
com.apple.springboard.rawOrientation    2.2 –
com.apple.springboard.curvedBatteryCapacity`

Comment: Thanks for these details, but I was actually looking for a Swift implementation. Sorry if I wasn't clearer.

Comment: You could probably figure out how to transfer it over with some research. You can also include ObjC in a Swift project.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look further into it.

Comment: com.apple.springboard.pluggedin does not give return any user info, Any idea how to achieve that